# Tableau Server Error connecting to ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, tableau-api

I can able to connect/fetch data from Tableau Desktop but in tableau server it is throwing below error with datasource, Datasource is build on BI ODBC driver. Access permission are assign granted to root folder Oracle_HOME.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, it seems the the driver is not properly installed. Try downloading the Oracle driver from tableau drivers page. If its installed correctly please cross check on the configurations you have provided. If you are using the ODBC driver, have you created the DSN properly. The DSN needs to be configured properly with the server name and authorisations and once this is done you can use this DSN in tableau.

Once you have installed the driver properly

Click Connect to Data.
On the Connect page, click Other Databases (ODBC).
In the DSN drop-down list, select the name that you gave to your Oracle BI Server ODBC connection, and then click Connect.

Below is the link on how to connect with the BI Connector

[How to Connect to Oracle BI Server with Tableau without the shortcomings of Oracle ODBC driver](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-9857)

Comment: I already looked into above given link, It did not helped. I am able to connect and build report from tableau desktop, when i publish same DS/ workbook on server it throws error on tableau server. Everything is on same machine, Tableau desktop/ Driver/ Tableau server. only obiee server is on different machine,

Comment: Check for the firewall settings so that the obiee server port is opened in the firewall

Comment: I found out solution,By Default, tableau server pre populates “Server Run As user” account  to Network Service account (NT AUTHRITY\NetworkService). And this account does not have full permission.

Answer (score 0):

By Default, tableau server pre-populates “Server Run As user” account  to Network Service account (NT AUTHRITY\NetworkService). And this account does not have full permission.

[image]